# React Native: How to implement a table with headers and values with fewest lines of code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flexbox, alignment

In my React Native app, I have an array of objects containing two fields, like this:

```
[
  {
    field1: a1,
    field2: a2,
  },
  {
    field1: b1,
    field2: b2,
  },
  {
    field1: c1,
    field2: c2,
  },
  {
    field1: d1,
    field2: d2,
  },
]
```

I want to loop through this array and display the data in a table that would look something like this:

[image]

The main criterion I want to figure out how to implement is to have "heading1" and "heading2" aligned with the contents of their respective columns, as shown in the image.

**Approach 1:** Render three columns, then loop through the array for each one, render a checkbox for each item in the first, render `field1` in the second, and `field2` in the third. The problem with this approach is that I'm re-creating the same loop three times.

**Approach 2:** Loop through the array once only; on the first iteration render `blank, "heading1", "heading2"`, and on subsequent iterations render `checkbox, field1, field2`. The problem with this approach is that I wouldn't be able to ensure that "heading1" and "heading2" are aligned with the rest of their respective columns without manually adding padding etc.

**My question is:** is there any approach that uses only one loop, as in Approach 2, but ensures "heading1" and "heading2" are aligned with their respective columns as in Approach 2?

Comment: Approach 2 should work just fine, you just need to create consistent styling for both your 'header' and 'content' items. Are you asking for styling help here or something else? I'm not quite sure how best to answer this question.

Comment: The problem with Approach 2 is that the horizontal position of "heading1" will be determined by the width of the blank space to the left of it. I'd have to render an empty element with width equal to the width of the checkbox elements in the subsequent rows. I could do this manually, but the width of the checkbox elements might change from device to device. Does that make sense? One thing I'm considering is rendering an actual checkbox instead of a blank element, but giving it height 0 so that it appears blank, but has the same width as the checkbox  elements below.

Comment: You can't sort it without a padding value.

Comment: You can make the width equal by using the width of the device

Comment: Another option would be to set flex values for each of the three rows. Your thought on rendering a checkbox with a zero height is also not bad if you wrap each row in its own view.